# Proving divisibility

Tags: discrete-mathematics, divisibility

Let $x,y$ and $m$ be integers. Prove if $m | 4x$ + y and $m | 7x+2y$ then $m|x$ and $m|y$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $u = 4x + y$ and $v = 7x + 2y$ so that $x = 2u - v$ and $y = 4v - 7u$.

Since $m | u$ and $m | v$ it also happens that $m | 2u - v$ and $m | 4v - 7u$.

That proves that $m | x$ and $m | y$.

Comment: Thanks, but how did you get x = 2u - v and y = 4v - 7u?? I can't see how you got those

Comment: Well u has 4x in it and v has 7x in it. So 2u - v will just have 1x in it. I was lucky and the ys cancelled out. Since I have x = something I could easily find y. This is called Gaussian elimination.

Comment: @Arvin: I'm not quanta but I'll take the liberty of trying to demistify it:
We have $u = 4x + y \Rightarrow 2u = 8x + 2y$
We also have $v = 7x + 2y$, we we now subtract the this equation from above one $2u - v = 8x + 2y - 7x - 2y \Rightarrow 2u - v = x$
Similarly for the other one.

Comment: Thanks guys! I got it now! it's so obvious once you get it

Comment: @Arvin: A simple way to see how the above equations arise is to use the matrix form in my answer. They arise from solving $\rm\ M\ \vec x = \vec u\ $ so $\rm \vec x =  M^{-1}\ \vec u\ $ where $\rm\:M\:$ is the matrix in my answer. But it's simpler to use  $\rm\ \vec u = \vec 0\ $ as in my answer.

Answer (score 6):

$\rm \bmod m\!:\ \begin{bmatrix} 4 & 1 \\ 7 & 2 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}\rm x \\ \rm y\end{bmatrix} \equiv \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}\, \Rightarrow\, \begin{bmatrix}\rm x\\ \rm y\end{bmatrix} \equiv \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}\ $ since the matrix is invertible $\rm (det = 1)$

Comment: That's a really good way to see it!

Answer (score 1):

You can also prove this using the following theorem. It is quite useful for proving things like this. It says:

Let $a, b, c$ be integers such that $a|b$ and $a|c$ where a is not equal to 0. Then $a|(bx+cy)$ where $x$ and $y$ are integers.

By hypothesis, you have $m|(4x+y)$ and $m|(7x+2y)$. Let's show first that $m|x$. Since $m|(4x+y)$ and $m|(7x+2y)$, by the above theorem, this implies that $m|(2)(4x+y)+(-1)(7x+2y)=x$, so therefore $m|x$. To prove that $m|y$, we do the same procedure as before but with different integers. Since $m|(4x+y)$ and $m|(7x+2y)$, this implies that $m|(-7)(4x+y)+(4)(7x+2y)=y$, so therefore $m|y$. Thus, we have proved that $m|x$ and $m|y$.

I really hope this helps!